# Rmatching strings across columns of two dataframes in R

Tags: r, string-matching

My apologies, in my haste to post my question I forgot to follow the basic rules of posting. I have edited my post in line with these rules:

R experts,
I appreciate that a similar question has been raised before but I am unable to adapt the solutions suggested before to my specific data problem. I basically have a dataframe (call it df1), where one of the columns is a string of sentences, part of which contains a city name and a country name. As an example, dataframe df1 has a column called bus_desc with the following data:

| bus_desc |
| --- |
| Company ABCD has a base capital of USD 5 million. Company ABCD is based in Mobile, Alabama, US. It is also known to have issued 10 million shares ..... |
| Company XYZ has a history of producing bolts. Company XYZ operates out of Delhi, India. Its directors decided to.... |

In another dataframe (call it df2), I have two columns of data (named city and country) where each row contains a city name and the corresponding country as follows:

| city | country |
| --- | --- |
| MOBILE | US |
| DELHI | INDIA |
| LONDON | UK |

I want R to search the string of sentences of each row for that column in dataframe df1, and match the city (and the same for country) against the city name (and also the country name) from the relevant column in dataframe df2. If there is a match, I want to create a column called city in dataframe df1 and extract the city name from dataframe df2 and assign it to the row in dataframe df1. My final output should look like this:

| bus_desc | city | country |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Company ABCD has a base capital of USD 5 million. Company ABCD is based in Mobile, Alabama, US. It is also known to have issued 10 million shares ..... | MOBILE | US |
| Company XYZ has a history of producing bolts. Company XYZ operates out of Delhi, India. Its directors decided to.... | DELHI | INDIA |

Can anyone please suggest a straightforward solution for this if it exists? I tried the below but it does not work

```
df1 <- df1 %>% rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(city=ifelse(grepl(toupper(bus_desc),df2$city),df2$city,df1))
```

Many thanks for your solutions and help on this.

Regards,
Dev

Answer (score 0):

You can use `str_extract` to extract the `city` and `country` values listed in `df2`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

df1 %>%
  mutate(city = str_extract(toupper(bus_desc), str_c(df2$city, collapse = '|')), 
         country = str_extract(toupper(bus_desc), str_c(df2$country, collapse = '|')))

                            bus_desc
#1 Company ABCD has a base capital of USD 5 million. Company ABCD is based in Mobile, Alabama, US. It is also known to have issued 10 million shares
#2                                  Company XYZ has a history of producing bolts. Company XYZ operates out of Delhi, India. Its directors decided to

#    city country
#1 MOBILE      US
#2  DELHI   INDIA
```

**data**

It is easier to help if you provide data in a [reproducible format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269) -

```
df1 <- data.frame(bus_desc = c('Company ABCD has a base capital of USD 5 million. Company ABCD is based in Mobile, Alabama, US. It is also known to have issued 10 million shares', 
                               'Company XYZ has a history of producing bolts. Company XYZ operates out of Delhi, India. Its directors decided to'))
df2 <- data.frame(city = c('MOBILE', 'DELHI', 'LONDON'), 
                  country = c('US', 'INDIA', 'UK'))
```

Comment: Hi Ronak, apologies for not using a reproducible code format to make the testing of the code easier. I will remember to do that in future posts. Thank you for the solution. Unfortunately, at my end, this is not running and it is either crashing R (getting a message that R needs to restart) or it is giving me a message  which I am unable to make sense of. Here is the error message thrown by R:

Comment: Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `city`. x Syntax error in regexp pattern. (U_REGEX_RULE_SYNTAX, context=`QAL EH-YE NOW|CHAGHCHARAN|LASHKAR GAH|ZARANJ|TARIN KOWT|ZAREH SHARAN|ASADABAD|TALOQAN|MAHMUD-E ERAQI|MEHTAR LAM|BARAKI BARAK|AYBAK|MAYDA SHAHR|KAROKH|SHEBERGHAN|POL-E KHOMRI|BALKH|MEYMANEH|ANDKHVOY|QALAT|GHAZNI|FEYZABAD|KONDOZ|JALALABAD|CHARIKAR|GARDIZ|BAMIAN|BAGHLAN|FARAH|HERAT|MAZAR-E SHARIF|KANDAHAR|KABUL|MARIEHAMN|KRUJE|FIER|LUSHNJE|PUKE|BAJRAM CURRI|KUKES|SARANDE|ERSEKE|POGRADEC|KORCE|BERAT|COROVODE|GRAMSH|LIBRAZHD|TEPELENE|PERMET|GJIROKASTER|PESHKOPI|BURREL|LEZHE|RRESHEN|

Comment: There are a few more cities (these are all city names) after the above with a | at the end but the error message is as above. Any suggestion would be much appreciated. - thank you.

Comment: How big is `df2` ? How many rows? It seems the regex cannot handle all city and country at once. So maybe you need to break them down and run in chunks. Also, I hope all the values in `df2` are unique.

Comment: thanks Ronak - df2 is actually quite big from the point of view of this string matching exercise. df2 has 12240 unique city-country pairs combinations. I have tried to split the search separately - matching country and city in separate lines of codes. The country match worked successfully only once, but every other attempt to match the strings has crashed R. I will keep trying this and hopefully might have some success with this. Thanks very much for your help on this - very much appreciated. Regards, Dev